# g++ does not link depending on optimization settings

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, linker

So, this is eating me for the last two days:

I can't link my application, depending on which compiler I use and what optimizations levels are used:

- `gcc` plays nicely with `-O1`, `-O2`, `-O3` but fails with `-O0` and
- `clang` plays nicely with `-O2` and `-O3` and fails with `-O1` and `-O0`.

There are a bunch of horrible templates in it, but I see no reason for this obscure behaviour.

Here is a minimal amount of code that reproduces the problem:

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using id_type = long;

class CB : public std::enable_shared_from_this<CB>
{
public:
    CB() = default;
    virtual ~CB() = default;
};

template<class F, class C> class SC : public CB
{
};

class FB
{
public:
    virtual ~FB() = default;
    template<class T, class B> T* as(B* v) const { return dynamic_cast<T*>(v);}
};

template<class T>
class F : public FB
{
public:
    virtual std::shared_ptr<CB> create() const
    {
        auto n = std::make_shared<T>();
        return n;
    }
};

struct  B
{
    virtual ~B() = default;
    static const id_type ID = 1;
};

class A : virtual public B, virtual public SC<A, B>
{
public:
    A() = default;
};

static std::map<id_type, std::shared_ptr<FB>> crtrs {
        {A::ID, std::make_shared<F<A>>()}
    };

int main()
{
    std::cout << crtrs.size();
}
```

Here is the same online https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/sb9b5E

And here are the error messages:

```sh
fld@flap ~/work/p/test1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
> $ g++ -O1 main.cpp                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
fld@flap ~/work/p/test1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
> $ g++ -O2 main.cpp                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
fld@flap ~/work/p/test1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
> $ g++ -O3 main.cpp                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
fld@flap ~/work/p/test1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
> $ g++ -O4 main.cpp                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
fld@flap ~/work/p/test1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
> $ g++ -O0 main.cpp                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
/tmp/cc8D7sNK.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1c0): undefined reference to `B::ID'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
fld@flap ~/work/p/test1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
> $ clang++ -O0 main.cpp                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
/tmp/main-c49b32.o: In function `__cxx_global_var_init.1':
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x7a): undefined reference to `B::ID'
clang-8: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
fld@flap ~/work/p/test1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
> $ clang++ -O1 main.cpp                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
/tmp/main-cf18ee.o: In function `__cxx_global_var_init.1':
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x3c): undefined reference to `B::ID'
clang-8: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
fld@flap ~/work/p/test1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
> $ clang++ -O2 main.cpp                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
fld@flap ~/work/p/test1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
> $ clang++ -O3 main.cpp
```

If someone has any ideas what might be the reason, any hints are more than welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not provide a definition of B::ID anywhere. It just happens that with higher optimization all accesses happened to be elided by the compiler.

You need to add the definition of a static member at toplevel scope:

```
const id_type B::ID;
```

If a static const data member is only read, it does not need a separate definition because compile time constants are not considered ODR-used ([One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition)).
The reason that you need the definition at all is that the map constructor expects `std::map::value_type` in the initializer list which is `std::pair<const Key, T>`. The constructor that gets picked in this case is `pair( const T1& x, const T2& y );`
In order to call this constructor the address of `A::ID` which is `B::ID` gets taken, which constitutes an ODR-use even for a constant.

Because the pair constructor is almost trivial in this case it gets inlined at higher optimization and the only reference to &B::ID disappears because B::ID's value is known and the pair can be directly initialized.

See also: [static](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static)

If you are using C++17 or newer, you can also make `B:ID` `constexpr` instead of `const`, then you do not need a separate definition, because `constexpr` is implicitly `inline` (`inline static const` should also be OK).

Comment: You are right, this indeed solves the error, but the problem is a bit more deeper than this, since the following: `static std::map<id_type, std::shared_ptr<FB>> crtrs {
        {1, std::make_shared<F<A>>()}
    };
int main()
{
    std::cout << A::ID;
}` compiles without problems. It has to do with something from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#ODR-use on how the static const is used, whether is address is taken, etc... Thanks for the direction!

Comment: It's also worth noting that in c++17 and up, a static member variable can be declared with _inline_, which causes the declaration to also be a definition, and not need to be defined in a cpp file--especially useful for an otherwise header-only file.  Analogous to an inline function defined in a header.

Comment: Constexpr is implicitly _inline_ in this case.